# Script for emailing Google Sheet to PDF | How to format dates in email subject line

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Have a script that I pulled from this forum and in most part it works great. Just having difficulty in coding around a couple of changes I have made.

1. I am generating the date (pulled from a cell in the sheet) and placing it in the email subject line, however it is auto formatting to include time and timezone. e.g. Wed Mar 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT+1300 (NZDT). I would like it to display as it is formatted in the sheet. e.g. Wed Mar 04.
2. Trying to make the first row of the sheet [row 3] and ignoring the first two rows when generating the PDF.

Any help much appreciated.

```
function emailPdf(){ // this is the function to call
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[3];
  var shName = sh.getName()

  sendSpreadsheetToPdf(3, shName, ('myemail@gmail.com'), sh.getRange('B3').getValue(), sh.getRange('B4').getValue(), sh.getRange('D28').getValue());
}
function sendSpreadsheetToPdf(sheetNumber, pdfName, email, subject, date, htmlbody) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
  var sheetId = sheetNumber ? spreadsheet.getSheets()[sheetNumber].getSheetId() : null;
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=A4'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    var mailOptions = {
      attachments:blob, htmlBody:htmlbody
    }
MailApp.sendEmail(
      email, 
      subject+" | "+date+" (" + pdfName +")", 
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);

MailApp.sendEmail(
      Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 
      subject+" | "+date+" (" + pdfName +")",
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

peruse:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
var prettyTime= Utilities.formatDate(date,'America/Los_Angeles', "EEE MMM dd" );
```

What happens if you hide the first two rows before converting to pdf?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Hiding the rows would normally work, however I am using these two rows to store a button and an IMPORTRANGE function. I have the date format working. BRILLIANT! Thanks.